# mod_rewrite activated by WordPress prevents directory access directives

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file placed in the root of my wordpress site:

```
AuthType basic
AuthName "enter password"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

It worked well with my previous hosting provider returning 401 if no/incorrect password provided but when I've moved to a new one in case if no/incorrect password the visitor still able to load index.php, but without images, stylesheets and may be other external parts of the site, I haven't checked.

When `#BEGIN WordPress / # END WordPress` part is removed then 401 error displayed, as it should.

Is there a way to override this behavior? Without touching `#BEGIN WordPress / # END WordPress` part as it has been added by WP and could be modified without my attention.

Also my provider claims it is normal behavior and I wonder if it's right or it just don't want to pay attention to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding `ErrorDocument 401 /401.php` to my `.htaccess`